# source .bashrc command doesn't work

Tags: bash

I installed TinyOS on RedHat for academic purposes. Now I can't log in to the system. I logged in in single user mode.

Then I tried to log in. I couldn't login as any user. I couldn't start the X server manually. When it boots up, the system doesn't start the X server.

Then I executed these commands

```
sh# hostname
(none)
sh# source .bashrc
```

bash-: gives a path relevant to TinyOS and says unable to find it

Then session stops.
Actually there is no such file.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Actually I figured it out.
There is a directory /etc/profile.d/ and when we log in with bash, all the .sh files are executed before others.
There is a tinyos.sh and It can't find the directory (that I have mentioned) when it executes.
That may be problem the system get stuck.

This is my fault. But I got some ideas.

I needed to find the file that execute environment variables in a different way. I search all the files that sets the EV. By mistakenly I found this. 

Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

what is the current shell ? Is it bash? `echo $0`

when you execute bash, try `. /path/to/.bashrc` and see if that loads the environment.